# For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, determine if the function is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know how to prove if a transformation is linear:
$T(\alpha \overset{\rightharpoonup}X + \overset{\rightharpoonup}Y) = \alpha T(\overset{\rightharpoonup}X) + T(\overset{\rightharpoonup}Y)$

For something in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{2} $ like $T(x,y) = (x+y,y)$ this is pretty simple and I like to write out $\overset{\rightharpoonup}a = (a_{1}, a_{2})$ and  $\overset{\rightharpoonup}b = (b_{1},b_{2})$ when proving this so as not to confuse with any $x$ and $y$ in the original question.

However now I am working on exercises involving matrices and $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and I am confused as to how to set up the proof with regards to these transformations:

a) $T(X_{n\times n}) = AX - XA$

b) $T(x_{n\times 1})= Ax + b$ for $b \neq 0$

c) $T(A) = A^{ \Gamma }$ (transpose)

d) $T(X_{n\times n}) = \frac{X+X^{\intercal}}{2}$

For the first one I have:

For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$:

$T(a+b) = A(a+b) - (a+b)A = (Aa + Ab)-(aA+bA) = Aa+Ab-aA -bA$
$T(a) = Aa - aA , T(b) = Ab - bA$
$T(a) + T(b) = Aa - aA + Ab - bA$
so $T(a+b) = T(a) + T(b)$
$T(ca) = A(ca) - (ca)A = c(Aa) - c(aA) = c(Aa - aA) = cT(a)$

so $T(X_{n\times n}) = AX - XA$ is linear. Am I going about this the right way?

For the second one I have:

$T(\overset{\rightharpoonup}a + \overset{\rightharpoonup}b) = A(\overset{\rightharpoonup}a + \overset{\rightharpoonup}b) + b = A\overset{\rightharpoonup}a + A\overset{\rightharpoonup}b + b$

$T(\overset{\rightharpoonup}a) + T(\overset{\rightharpoonup}b) = A\overset{\rightharpoonup}a + A\overset{\rightharpoonup}b + 2b$

$T(\overset{\rightharpoonup}a + \overset{\rightharpoonup}b) \neq T(\overset{\rightharpoonup}a) + T(\overset{\rightharpoonup}b)$

so $T(x_{n\times 1})= Ax + b$ for $b \neq 0$ is not linear.

For the third one I have:

$T(a+b) = (a+b)^{\intercal} = a^{\intercal} + b^{\intercal} = T(a) + T(b)$

$T(ca) = (ca)^{\intercal} = c(a^{\intercal}) = cT(a)$
so it is linear.

For the last one I have:

$T(a+b) = \frac{a+b)+(a+b)^{\intercal}}{2} = \frac{a+b+a^{\intercal}+b^{\intercal}}{2}$

$T(a)+T(b) = \frac{a+a^{\intercal}}{2} + \frac{b+b^{\intercal}}{2} =  \frac{a+b+a^{\intercal}+b^{\intercal}}{2}$

$T(ca) = \frac{ca+ca^{\intercal}}{2} = c\frac{a+a^{\intercal}}{2} = cT(a)$

So $T(X_{n\times n}) = \frac{(X+X^{\intercal})}{2}$ is also linear

Comment: yeah, your proof is correct

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question to include my proofs for the other 3. Sorry could you please let me know if those look correct as well?

Comment: yes of corse your answer is correct, but for b) you can get et directly if you see that $T(0)=b\neq 0$.